# Uninitialized local variable used

Tags: c

I get the following error with my code:

> error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'str_day' used

I'm compiling in Visual Studio Express 2012

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void separate (char *join, char *tempmonth, int *tempday){
    //function to separate month and day from a string
    char *p ;
    p = strtok(join," ");
    strcpy(tempmonth,p);                    // Write the month in tempmonth 
    p = strtok(NULL," ");
    *tempday = atoi(p);                     // Write the day to tempday
}   

int main(){
    char month[20],tempmonth[20],join[30];
    char *str_day;
    int day,tempday;
    printf("Enter the month: ");
    scanf("%s",month);
    printf("Enter the day: ");
    scanf("%d",&day);
    strcpy(join,month);                         
    strcat(join," ");                               //add the month and day seperating by space
    sprintf(str_day,"%d",day);                      //convert day to string to concatenate with month
    strcat(join,str_day);
    separate(join,tempmonth,&tempday);              //call to function separate 
    printf("Month: %s, Day: %d\n",tempmonth,tempday);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: As the message indicates. You have not initialised the local variable str_day. It is a pointer that doesn't point anywhere. You need a character array to put your string in.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
char *str_day;
```

with

```
char *str_day = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

where n is the number of chars your want. str_day must show somewhere (in other words, be initialized) in order to use it.
Otherwise, use an array of characters, like

```
char str_day[n];
```

where again n is the number of chars your want.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.

Comment: This is why I used n * sizeof (char).

Comment: If `sizeof(char)` is always one, there's no point in multiplying anything by it.

Comment: By using n * sizeof (char), you can allocate as many chars as you wish.

Comment: After you allocate memory you should use `snprintf(str_day, n, "%d",day);` in order not to break the memory boundaries (or in this particular case, ensure that n is big enough to store all possible numbers including sign)

Comment: *By using n * sizeof (char), you can allocate as many chars as you wish.*  n times one will always be **n**.  Multiplying by one is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the declaration and usage of `str_day`

```
char *str_day;
sprintf(str_day,"%d",day);
```

`str_day` is an uninitialised pointer.  It's value is indeterminate, and even accessing its value (to pass that value to `sprintf()`) gives undefined behaviour.  That is what the compiler is warning about.

Even worse, `sprintf()` will treat whatever value it receives as if it is an array of `char` long enough to write the value of `day` to using the format `%d`.  The result of that - since `str_day` is uninitialised - is also undefined.  In practice, `sprintf()` will probably overwrite some memory it shouldn't.

To fix the problem either change `str_day` to an array of char

```
char str_day[10];
```

or allocate a buffer for it to point at.

```
char *str_day = malloc(10);

 /* do your work here */

free(str_day);    /*  when finished with it */
```

In both cases above, I have assumed 9 characters is enough to hold a value of `day`.